# Is calling clear() on an ifstream problematic?

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, iostream

I have a function that reads from a file with a fixed format in a loop like so:

```
istream.seekg(0, std::ios::begin);
while (istream >> x >> y) {
  // do something
}
```

As I discovered and as has been well documented here after the loop exits both `eofbit` and `failbit` are set. I want to be able to re-read the file again the next time the function is called without closing and re-opening the `ifstream` so to get this to work I have to add an `istream.clear()` first. It seems odd to me that since c++11 the documented behavior of `seekg()` says it will clear `eofbit` but it doesn't do anything with `failbit` which kind of makes this aspect of `seekg()` seem useless to me. In any case, is calling `clear()` in any way problematic such as hiding any potential error conditions, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me just be very precise in the terminology here. The loop ends when either the bad bit or the fail bit is set, but it happens that when the eof bit is set the fail bit gets set as well.

The `bad` bit signals more serious (unrecoverable) errors so if you check that `istream.bad()` is false, calling `clear` to reuse the stream should be just fine.

Comment: Why did the `seekg()` behavior change to clear `eofbit` but not `failbit`? That seems odd to me given that `eofbit` and `failbit` will both be set.